# Subfolder save is causing variable not defined error, but it's in my first sub?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a separate sub that saves the last file in my array, but it still doesn't work when I redefine the variables within that second sub. How can I implement the variables in the second sub to allow the final file cut to be saved off into it's sub folder?

```
Sub SaveCopy(Wb As Workbook, Last)

Wb.SaveCopyAs strNewPath & _
              ValidFileName(Last & " - Shift Differential Roster_New Hire.xlsx")
End Sub
```

getting an error on `strNewPath` variable, but it's defined above at the top of the script?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim Data, Last
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, a As Long
Dim Dest As Range
Dim BASEPATH As String, strNewPath As String, strFileName As String

Dim strHRBP As String
Dim strEC As String

Dim colEC As Long
colEC = 1
Dim colHRBP As Long
colHRBP = 3
Set Wb = Workbooks("JNav Template.xlsx")

Set Dest = Wb.Sheets("New Hires_Internal&External").Range("A2")

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cuts")
    Data = .Range("L2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With
Wb.Activate

BASEPATH = "C:\Users\pp87255\Desktop\JNav Rest\"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = 1 To UBound(Data)

    If Data(i, 4) <> Last Then

        If i > 1 Then

            Dest.Select

            With Wb.Worksheets("New Hires_Internal&External")
                .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
            End With

            strNewPath = BASEPATH & strEC & "\"
            If Len(Dir(strNewPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
                MkDir strNewPath
            End If
            strNewPath = strNewPath & strHRBP & "\"
            If Len(Dir(strNewPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
                MkDir strNewPath
            End If

            Wb.SaveCopyAs strNewPath & _
                          ValidFileName(Last & " - Shift Differential Roster_New Hire.xlsx")

        End If

        With Wb.Sheets("New Hires_Internal&External")
            .Rows(2 & ":" & .Rows.Count).ClearContents
        End With

        strEC = Data(i, 1)
        strHRBP = Data(i, 3)
        Last = Data(i, 4)

        j = 0
    End If

    a = 0
    For k = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
        Dest.Offset(j, a) = Data(i, k)
        a = a + 1
    Next

    j = j + 1

Next

SaveCopy Wb, Last                            '<< save the last report


End Sub

Sub SaveCopy(Wb As Workbook, Last)

Wb.SaveCopyAs strNewPath & _
              ValidFileName(Last & " - Shift Differential Roster_New Hire.xlsx")
End Sub
```

Comment: Scope. `SaveCopy` doesn't know what `strNewPath` is. You can add it as a parameter of `SaveCopy`.

Comment: when I implement `Dim strNewPath as string` in the `SaveCopy` sub, it gets to my last file and says `Runtime error 1004: Microsoft Excel cannot access this file`

Comment: You want to add it as a *parameter*, just like `Wb` and `Last`.

Comment: @BigBen like: `Sub SaveCopy(Wb As Workbook, strNewPath As String, Last)`?

Comment: Yes, like that.

Comment: so I did that, and then implemented it here: `SaveCopy Wb, strNewPath, Last` and no error, but it doesn't show the file nor the folder for that last file

Comment: If `strNewPath` is missing the trailing backslash (\\), then you have a file one directory higher named `...\lastdirectoryinpathFileName.xlsx` instead of `...\lastdirectoryinpath\FileName.xlsx`

Comment: @FreeMan I stepped through in the locals window and noticed that the last file is saving in the previously referenced directory sub folder. The `if(len....` statements have the trailing backslash. What could I change in my code to ensure that it creates a new folder?

Comment: @freeman for example: if my second last folder is saved under `EC4` > `HRBP 5`
and my last file should be saved under `EC 5` > `HRBP 1`, it will save in the `EC4` > `HRBP 5` folder instead of creating the last directory

Comment: @BigBen found the culprit. I omitted the `If I > 1 Then` statement and now it runs fine... So odd.. Can you label your comment in an answer so I can credit you for the help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple issue of scope.

`SaveCopy` doesn't know what `strNewPath` is. The `strNewPath` variable is defined within `Main` and consequently is not visible outside it.

Add a file path parameter to `SaveCopy`:

```
Sub SaveCopy(Wb as Workbook, strNewPath as String, Last as Variant)
    ...
End Sub
```

And call `SaveCopy` like this:

```
SaveCopy Wb, strNewPath, Last
```

Comment: Thank you!! This, along with omitting an earlier of statement fixed the issue!

Comment: Great! [Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-scope-and-visibility) a good article on scope if you need further reading.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be that strEC and strHRBP, and Last are defined at the end of the for loop. try moving assigning those variable to the beginning. Essentially you are try to go to your last assignment but your code is finished. 
Another option is:
    For i = 1 to Ubound(data) + 1

Comment: I tried the +1 on the first for loop, but it errors out on the `if data(I,4) <> Last Then` part on the last run through

Comment: Also, my variables are shown correctly when I hover over on the last loop and are shown in my locals window, but the strNewPath is caught up in the second to last folder created. Would that ordering of variables in the code cause that Hang up on the last loop through?

Comment: Is your loop stopping short of what you want it to? Maybe try:

Comment: For i = 0 to UBound(Data)

Comment: Just trying to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: moving my variables up just before the first for/next loop is actually not even triggering folder creations. also, appending the +1 to the 1 to Ubound is causing the same issue. THis is the weirdest error I've come across so far in my time of learning VBA

Comment: found the culprit. I omitted the `If I > 1 Then` statement and now it runs fine... So odd

Comment: Yeah, arrays start from 0 so that would make sense. Glad you figured it out!